# How can I parallelize this calculation?

Tags: parallelization

I need to compute a sum function:
$$E=\frac{(2 \gamma )}{\delta ^2} \sum _{m,n,p,q=0}^{\text{mMax}-1} a_m a_n a_p a_q \text{A}(m) \text{A}(n) \text{A}(p) \text{A}(q) \text{D}\left(\frac{1}{2} (m+n+p+q)\right) \delta _{m+n,p+q} \cos (b_m+b_n-b_p-b_q)$$

where the a's, b's and $\gamma$ are real numbers and m,n,p,q are integers, $\delta_{m+n,p+q}$ is the Kronecker delta, and the functions are:

$$\text{A}(\text{n$\_$})\text{:=}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\delta ^{2 n} \left(\delta  n! \, _1F_1\left(-n-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2};-\frac{\xi ^2}{\delta ^2}\right)+2 \xi  \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right) \, _1F_1\left(-n;\frac{3}{2};-\frac{\xi ^2}{\delta ^2}\right)\right)}}$$

$$D(x)=\frac{1}{2}\bar{\delta}^{2x+1}\left[\bar{\delta}\Gamma(x+1)\,_{1}F_{1}\left(-x-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2};-\frac{\xi^{2}}{\bar{\delta}^{2}}\right)+2\xi\Gamma\left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right)\,_{1}F_{1}\left(-x;\frac{3}{2};-\frac{\xi^{2}}{\bar{\delta}^{2}}\right)\right],$$
where 1F1 is the confluent Hypergeometric function, $\Gamma$ the Gamma function, $\xi$ and $\delta$ (not to be confused with the Kronecker delta) are positive real numbers and $\bar{\delta}=\delta/\sqrt2$.

To me it seems like it should be possible to parallelize the calculation, since each of the terms corresponding to values of the sum $m+n$ can be computed independently. However the `Parallelize` function does not work. My question is: is it possible to parallelize this computation, and if so, how?

EDIT: Here's the equations in Wolfram language:

```
interactionEnergy = ((2*γ)/δ^2)*\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(m = 0\), \(mMax - 1\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(n = 0\), \(mMax - 1\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(p = 0\), \(mMax - 1\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(q = 0\), \(mMax - 1\)]a[m]*a[n]*
        a[p]*a[q]*Cos[b[m] + b[n] - b[p] - b[q]]*Acof[p]*Acof[m]*
        Acof[q]*Acof[n]*Dcof[\((m + n + p + q)\)/2]*
        KroneckerDelta[m + n, p + q]\)\)\)\);


Acof[n_] := √(1/(δ^(2*n)*(n! *δ*
         Hypergeometric1F1[-n - 1/2, 1/2, -(ξ^2/δ^2)] + 
        2*ξ*Gamma[n + 3/2]*
         Hypergeometric1F1[-n, 3/2, -ξ^2/δ^2])))


Dcof[x_] := (1/2)*(δ^(2*x + 1)/
    2^(x + 1/2))*((δ/(√2)) Gamma[x + 1]*
     Hypergeometric1F1[-x - 1/2, 1/2, -2*ξ^2/δ^2] + 
    2*ξ*Gamma[x + 3/2]*
     Hypergeometric1F1[-x, 3/2, -2*ξ^2/δ^2])
```

Comment: Can you share your input in Wolfram Language input syntax?
Parallelization unfortunately is much less straightforward than it probably should be (and with unexpected effects), but your example should be parallelizable.

Comment: Sure :), I'll do that as soon as I find out how to write Mathematica code in here.

Comment: Ok, I think it should be legible now.

Comment: Please use the `Sum` function.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the suggestion and sorry for asking such a simple question.